# POST 400 Bad request, React, Node/Express, MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I'm learning to build a simple MERN application to take user data and upload it to a mongoDB collection, and I can't seem to figure out why I'm receiving a 400 BAD REQUEST error when attempting to post the user data. It's currently being run on local server. I'm currently unable to find a post that directly solves my particular issue.

Here is my data.js for the data schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const data = new Schema(
    {
        x: Number,
        y: Number,
        z: Number,
        r: Number,
        g: Number,
        b: Number
    },
    { collection: "cube" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("data", DataSchema);
```

My server.js backend:

```
// JavaScript source code
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");
const Data = require("./data");
const cors = require("cors");

const API_PORT = 3000;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

//MongoDB database
const dbRoute = "mongodb+srv://testuser:testuserpw@alexcluster-alfjn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";

mongoose.connect(
    dbRoute,  
    { useNewUrlParser:true }
);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to database"));

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger("dev"));

//this is our add method
//add method to add data into database
router.post ("/putData", (req, res) => {
    let data = new Data(req.body);

    data.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.json('Values added successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});

app.use("/api", router);
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log('Listening on port ${API_PORT}'));
```

And finally my App.js frontend:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        r: 0,
        g: 0,
        b: 0
    };

    addData = (xVal, yVal, zVal, rVal, gVal, bVal) => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/putData", {
            x: xVal,
            y: yVal,
            z: zVal,
            r: rVal,
            g: gVal,
            b: bVal
        })
        .then(response => { 
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response)
        });
// reset state
        // this.setState({
        //     x: 0,
        //     y: 0,
        //     z: 0,
        //     r: 0,
        //     g: 0,
        //     b: 0
        // })

    };

//UI
    render(){
        return (
            <div>  
                <ul>
                    <p> Please enter all applicables values for x, y, z, and r, g, b. </p>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <label> X </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="360" onChange={e => this.setState({x: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <label> Y </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="360" onChange={e => this.setState({y: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <label> Z </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="360" onChange={e => this.setState({z: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <label> R </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="255" onChange={e => this.setState({r: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <label> G </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="255" onChange={e => this.setState({g: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <label> B </label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="255" onChange={e => this.setState({b: e.target.value})} placeholder="0" style={{width:"40px"}} />
                    <button onClick={() => this.addData(this.state.x, this.state.y, this.state.z, this.state.r, this.state.g, this.state.b)}>
                    Add
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

According to the console in Google Chrome, this is where I receive the error:

[![Full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUAog.png)

I'm currently unsure why I'm receiving this error, where the culprit lies and what I can do to fix it.

EDIT1: Edited with the error message.

Comment: Have you tried printing the error message? Instead of just returning a 400 when you hit an error. If you update your question with that error it might be much easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Edited with the full error message. It seems to be pointing to xhr.js line 173, telling it it has Failed to load resource, and thus the 400 error.

Comment: Thats not the error I was referring to though. Thats not really an error since your nodejs code is returning the 400. That is working as expected. Add console.log(err) to this line -
 .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
And you will see the error printed on your nodejs console.

Comment: Did you try to use Postman or Curl to test the Express API?

Comment: On the suggestion of Nick, it was the cors that wasn't implemented properly on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two main problems that are preventing your code from working:

You're not exporting your Schema from data.js properly:

Change your module.exports from

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("data", DataSchema);
```

to

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("data", data);
```

You are referencing the schema as data here `const data = new Schema(...)`.

As well you are also getting a CORS error because you have not used it in your server.js. You need to add:

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

To your server.js file above:

```
// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

That got it working on my localhost. However, I would highly advise against using that setup in a production environment. Check out the CORS module for more setup options:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: As it turns out it was the cors not working properly. This is my own mistake. Also fixed the various other aspects. After downloading the cors to my backend it started working properly.